# How to get the add the query string to actionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The below link gives be the following url: http://localhost:11111/files/Details/3

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "mycontroller", new { id = item.id },null)
```

But I'm trying to have a url parameter like this http://localhost:11111/files/Details?id=3 or http://localhost:11111/files/Details.aspx?id=3

How do I get the actionlink to show the url like details?i=3

Here is my controller View:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
       ...
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue? What error are you getting when you try to use the example link? Please be more specific about the current behavior when requesting help.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to see the parameter's name in the link?

Asp.Net MVC uses user-friendly URLs.

If you have created a project in Visual Studio using the MVC template, probally your routes, by default, are configured to interpret the parameter after the controller/action/ like the id.

So the id parameter's value in your action will be automatically replaced, by model binding, with the id number present in you URL.

Answer (score 0):

The routing codes can be found under the RegisterRoutes method in the Global.asax file of our project.

I see a cookie already in the RegisterRoutes method.

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Default",     // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}",     // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }    // Parameter defaults);
```

Using the MapRoute method above, we defined a new route.

**Sample ;**

```
public class HaberController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult Listele()
      {
           // Listing codes will be written
            return View("Listele");
      }

      public ActionResult Detay(string HaberId)
      {
           // Detail codes will be written
           return View("Detay");
      }
}
```

We go to our Global.asax file and edit it as follows.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapRoute(
             "HaberListeleme",
             "Haber",
             new { controller = "Haber", action = "Listele" }
       );

       routes.MapRoute(
            "HaberDetay",
            "Haber/{id}",
            new { controller = "Haber", action = "Detay" }
        );

       routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults
        );
}
```

If we do the routing as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "HaberDetay",
      "Haber/{*Id}",
      new { controller = "Haber", action = "Detay" }
);
```

So if we write * by putting the character next to our parameter name, it will be sent to the related parameter of the Detail method in the Controller, no matter what it says after the News / url tab.

**For example:**

> http://www.doguhanaydeniz.com/Haber/Turkiye/Guncel/34389

If a URL is requested as Turkey / current / 34389 will be sent as a parameter.

Comment: The above answer is the correct one. If you had more parameters e.g. - @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "mycontroller", new { id = item.id, item2=2 item3 = "3" },null) then this would become http://localhost:11111/files/Details/3?item2=2&item3=3 which adds the query parameters. Unless you have a reason to change I would go with the default MVC template. If you change the action from int? id to say int? userId you will get the querystring you are looking for